# Java - Connected scrollbars but in different positions

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I've tried using this:

```
 scroller2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(scroller.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());
```

To connect two scrollbars so that when you drag one, the other one moves. This is implemented via an actionlistener from a checkbox. However, this makes scroller2 jump to the position of scroller1. I want them to be connected, but remain in their respective positions. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably need to register an `AdjustmentListener` on each scrollbar, where the listener is aware of the other scrollbar, along with the flag which indicates they're currently connected.  You might need to be careful near edges, although `setValue()` might handle that without throwing any exception.

Comment: @AndrewS I've been trying to set the value of scroller2 to the value of scroller using an AdjustmentListener as follows: scroller2.setValue(scroller.getValue + offset). I'm planning on making the offset amount the distance between scroller and scroller2. However, any amount of the offset causes both scrollers to be stuck and their maximum values and not move..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `offset`, but this seems to work:

```
public class ConnectedScrollBarsApp {
    private static volatile boolean isConnected;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Connected Scroll Bars");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane leftScrollPane = getScrollPane("left", 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(leftScrollPane);

        JCheckBox connectedCheckBox = getConnectedCheckBox();
        frame.getContentPane().add(connectedCheckBox);

        JScrollPane rightScrollPane = getScrollPane("right", 100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rightScrollPane);

        setUpScrollBarAdjustmentListener(leftScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar(), rightScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar(), connectedCheckBox);
        setUpScrollBarAdjustmentListener(rightScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar(), leftScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar(), connectedCheckBox);

        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void setUpScrollBarAdjustmentListener(JScrollBar source, JScrollBar otherScrollBar, JCheckBox connectedCheckBox) {
        ConnectedScrollBarAdjustmentListener listener = new ConnectedScrollBarAdjustmentListener(otherScrollBar, source.getValue(), connectedCheckBox);
        source.addAdjustmentListener(listener);
    }

    private static JScrollPane getScrollPane(String side, int lineCount) {
        String panelContent = getPanelContent(side, lineCount);
        JTextArea panelArea = new JTextArea(panelContent);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panelArea);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private static JCheckBox getConnectedCheckBox() {
        ToggleScrollBarConnectionListener checkBoxListener = new ToggleScrollBarConnectionListener();
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Connected?");
        checkBox.addActionListener(checkBoxListener);
        return checkBox;
    }

    private static String getPanelContent(String side, int lineCount) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= lineCount; i++) {
            sb.append("This is ");
            sb.append(side);
            sb.append(" line ");
            sb.append(i);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static class ToggleScrollBarConnectionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isConnected = ((JCheckBox) e.getSource()).isSelected();
        }
    }

    private static class ConnectedScrollBarAdjustmentListener implements AdjustmentListener {
        private final JScrollBar otherScrollBar;
        private int thisPreviousValue;
        private final JCheckBox connectedCheckBox;

        public ConnectedScrollBarAdjustmentListener(JScrollBar otherScrollBar, int thisPreviousValue, JCheckBox connectedCheckBox) {
            this.otherScrollBar = otherScrollBar;
            this.thisPreviousValue = thisPreviousValue;
            this.connectedCheckBox = connectedCheckBox;
        }

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            if (!isConnected) {
                this.thisPreviousValue = e.getValue();
                return;
            }

            connectedCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            isConnected = false;
            JScrollBar thisScrollBar = (JScrollBar) e.getSource();

            double thisScrollBarPreviousRelativePosition = getRelativePosition(thisScrollBar, thisPreviousValue);
            double thisScrollBarLatestRelativePosition = getRelativePosition(thisScrollBar, e.getValue());
            double thisScrollBarRelativePositionChange = thisScrollBarLatestRelativePosition - thisScrollBarPreviousRelativePosition;

            int otherScrollBarCurrentPosition = otherScrollBar.getValue();
            int otherScrollBarNewPosition = (int) (otherScrollBarCurrentPosition + (otherScrollBar.getMaximum()  * thisScrollBarRelativePositionChange));

            otherScrollBar.setValue(otherScrollBarNewPosition);
            thisPreviousValue = e.getValue();
            isConnected = true;
            connectedCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
        }

        private double getRelativePosition(JScrollBar scrollBar, double value) {
            return value / scrollBar.getMaximum();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew S, this works perfectly in your example however when I use it in my project one scrollbar still jumps back to the position of the other. I have no idea why this is the case.

Comment: Actually, in your example the scrollbars are not actually retaining their positions. For example, say scrollbar 1 is at 30% and scrollbar 2 is at 70%. The user clicks the checkbox to connect them and moves scrollbar 1 to 20%. Scrollbar 2 should move to 60% along with it. However, right now scrollbar 2 jumps to 30% and then scrolls back to 20% with the first scrollbar.

Comment: I updated to adjust the other scroll bar based on the relative change of the scroll bar  being changed by the user.  Also, during the handling of the event the `isConnected` flag is set to false to avoid adjustment events bouncing back and forth between the scroll bars.  Also, the check box is disabled to make sure all events are handled before the check box can be unchecked.

Comment: that works beautifully. I'll try it on my project soon. Thanks so much!